# Request Twitter trends using Python and explore local trends: the code give {'errors': [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]}

Tags: python

I want to request Twitter trends using Python and explore local trends. Twitter categorizes trends (popular hashtags) by country or location, i.e. Worldwide,  Canada, Toronto.
The following are the codes with the last one giving the error.
I appreciate your help with any suggestions.

```
import pickle
import os
if not os.path.exists('secret_twitter_credentials.pkl'):
    Twitter={}
    Twitter['Consumer Key'] = ''
    Twitter['Consumer Secret'] = ''
    Twitter['Access Token'] = ''
    Twitter['Access Token Secret'] = ''
    with open('secret_twitter_credentials.pkl','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(Twitter, f)
else:
    Twitter=pickle.load(open('secret_twitter_credentials.pkl','rb'))
```

```
!pip install twitter==1.17.1
```

> Requirement already satisfied: twitter==1.17.1 in c:\users\elidb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.17.1)

```
import twitter
from twitter import oauth

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(Twitter['Access Token'],Twitter['Access Token Secret'],Twitter['Consumer Key'],Twitter['Consumer Secret'])          

twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

print(twitter_api)
```

> twitter.api.Twitter object at 0x0000020BB2D4FF08

```
WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
CA_WOE_ID = 23424775
LOCAL_WOE_ID=4118
world_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=WORLD_WOE_ID)
us_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=CA_WOE_ID)
local_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=LOCAL_WOE_ID)
```

> **TwitterHTTPError**: Twitter sent status 400 for URL: 1.1/trends/place.json using parameters: (id=1&oauth_consumer_key=&oauth_nonce=6310931814904808142&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1574346315&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=tmHU8Hh%2Bekoj6SocWz1OwfvLefA%3D)
>   **details: {'errors': [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]}**

Comment: This question is off topic for this site, it belongs on Stack Overflow really.

Comment: I strongly agree with you, but I was not able to post it there.